# No signing identity found

Tags: xcode

After I downloaded a app's source code from a university's website, Xcode never built and said :No signing identity found.

I can not even build my own app, but all the app wrote before still worked fine. Why is that?

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

I have figured out that all the settings are remained same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to  target in your app and select General tab.. you'll find a strange Bundle identifier and team is not assigned or assigned to team from your university..

You can try to change the team to your team.. and change the Identifier to something you already have (for trail) .. if it works you need to create new ID on your developer account on itunes .. or even better create a wild card identifier for cases like this.